# Are images copied to Xcode project

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

Ive had some svn woes with an Xcode project and now using an older version from another user (we've taken it out of svn now).

Trouble is it looks like images have been lost on the way. Or more correctly, they load in the app when testing locally, but when I Archive the app and add to [Testflight](http://apps.facebook.com/road_trip_test/) the images arent complied with the .ipa

There are alot of images and its really hard to tell what has been copied to the project and what is being taken locally. Is there a method of finding out how to do this more easily than deleting the image out of the app's file system, then from inside xcode then re-adding them from a local copy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer was to go into the Build Rules, delete all the image from the Copy Bundle Resources section and re add them to the project - fun!

Answer (score 0):

Go to SCM from Left hand side project explorer.

Expand SCM -> you will find images in red color which are in SCM but not on your local.

You have to right click-> Update it
Then open you project in Finder and find your image and just create relative path in your project.

Hope it helps....

Comment: @daidai : Below Targets you will find Executables; Below it Findresults; Below it Bookmarks; Below it you can find SCM. If you still cant find it check whether you have configured SCM in your project.

Comment: I u have updated from svn now simply open your project in Finder and find that images. Now drag them into your project and assure that Copy into desination group is unchecked. Hope it helps you..

Comment: This is the problem. I dont know which have been added to the project, there are 100s.

Comment: For configuring svn use this [link](http://developer.apple.com/tools/subversionxcode.html)

Comment: As stated in the question : we've taken it out of svn now.

Comment: You cant import image from svn if you are not currently connected. You have to connect it and then you can import images in your project..

Comment: Go to the "File" menu and click "Add Files to <your project> ...", this will open a file browser. The already-in-project files are greyed, there should be others you can click on. After adding those they will be in your app-file after next build.